# Programmatically select record in TDBLookupComboBox

Tags: database, combobox, c++builder

I am using a couple ADOQuery's to insert records in a database, one being tied to a DBLookupComboBox.  I want the user to be able to insert a record, leave the DBLookupComboBox blank, and programmatically select a value in that combo box for them.  I am fairly certain this is simple, I just can't find the exact code needed to do it.

I was hoping that I could just flip through records in the ADOQuery that is filling the combo box and set it on the record I am looking for, but when the code goes to do the Post it throws an exception about not being able to enter null values into the table (as in, the combo box was still sending nothing, instead of the new value)

Does anyone know what I would need to change to get this to work?

Comment: A really cheap solution is this:  SendMessage(DBLookupComboBox1->Handle, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_DOWN, 0);   But I really rather access the actual information.  SendMessage feels too much like a hack when I am certain there is a correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was even simpler than I had imagined.

```
ADOQueryToUpdate->FieldByName("Column_Name")->AsInteger = ADOQueryFillingList->FieldByName("Column_Name")->AsInteger;
```

Earlier I was trying to cast and use FieldByName()->Value (which is a variant) and this wasn't working.  Simply use AsInteger and it will update the ComboBox as you expect.

Sadly, I wish there was a bigger support interest in C++ Builder.